# Add a value to an id only if it is empty

Tags: jquery, html, dropzone

I want to add an id if the current id is empty. I thought this would do the job:

```
$(".file-row[id='']").attr('id', 'imageId'+imageId);
```

But it doesn't. Why not?

Comment: is the id attribute there at all?

Comment: use prop instead attr. I warn you. it wont work the way you think i will do

Comment: Yes it is, that .file-row get's added by dropzoneJS and also a id attribute is added.

Comment: Also you need to use the selector this way: `$(".file-row:not([id])")`

Comment: Hopefully this logic will only catch a single element cause, ya know, duplicate ids === bad

Comment: @Taplar that's exactly what i had before this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets the id if the id is blank, or missing all together.

```js
$('div').filter('[id=""],:not([id])').prop('id', 'newId');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="">One</div>
<div>Two</div>
<div id="three">Three</div>
```